# php script to recognize text from link

Tags: php

I was trying to create a script in php, for displaying messages. If the messages includes a web address, then this address I wanted to be displayed as a link. This is my code that works successfuly:

```
<?php 

if( (substr( $message, 0, 8 ) === "https://") || (substr( $message, 0, 7 ) === "http://") ){
    echo "<a href='$message' target='_blank'> $message </a>"; 
}else{
    echo " $message "; 
}

?>
```

It is working perfect if the user inserts in message a web address only like: **"http://google.com"** The problem starts if the users inserts a text before or after the web address. For example if writes: **"visit http://google.com site"** then it is making all the phrase as a link and it does not recognises the words with the web address. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Instead of dumping the whole $message into the "href" attribute, you need to find the longest legal URL starting with "http" (index 0) and only use that portion in the href. Assuming $message always starts at position 0 (you have been copying it to the output 1 character at a time?), you examine it character-by-character to build the longest legal URL, and use that portion of $message in the href. Bonus points for converting a URL Query String back to human-readable characters for the text portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [filter_var](http://php.net/filter_var) with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`:

```
$words = explode(" ", $message);
$_words = array();
foreach($words as $word){
    if(filter_var($word, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
    $_words[] = $word;
    }
    else{
    $_words[] = "<a href=\"$word\">$word</a>";
    }
}
echo implode(" ", $_words);
```

Demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mu8-vg5

Comment: Any idea how to modify the above code, so that if the user inserts directly a web address like "google.com" without http://in front of address will also work?

Comment: yes it is perfect, I saw this ...but it is not working if someone writes google.com instead of http : //google.com .Is there any posibility to change this so that it will recognizes addresses starting directcly with " www. "

Comment: Look at the difference.. http://3v4l.org/HWbgG is not working below 5.1.6. Then look at this: http://3v4l.org/vJTgr it's easier, cleaner and works for every version of PHP :) @user2491321

Comment: @JoranDenHouting If the OP is using the latest version of PHP, it doesn’t matter how many versions support his/her code. Remember that PHP is a server-side script and using new features doesn’t affect the experience of people who visit a website. Now it’ll be kind of you to withdraw the downvote if you’re the one who gave it to my answer.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta so how do you know which version he was using?

Answer (score 1):

I use this within a class:

```
public static function CreateLinks($text) {
        return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

To use it without a class, do this:

```
$message = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);
```

So in a test case this:

```
$message = "Hello, take a look at http://www.google.com or wait! Maybe you where looking for http://www.bing.com";

$message = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);

echo $message;
```

Will output:

```
Hello, take a look at <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">http://www.google.com</a> or wait! Maybe you where looking for <a href="http://www.bing.com" target="_blank">http://www.bing.com</a>
```

So, at the end your code can be replaced by just one single line! Replace this:

```
if( (substr( $message, 0, 8 ) === "https://") || (substr( $message, 0, 7 ) === "http://") ){
    echo "<a href='$message' target='_blank'> $message </a>"; 
}else{
    echo " $message "; 
}
```

by this:

```
$message = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w-.~:/?#\[\]\@!$&\'()*+,;=%]*)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jan Goyvaerts, Regex Guru, describe pretty well in his blog

http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

To find all matches in a multi-line string, use

```
preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

you can use preg_match function to get single match